# Nginx POST request is changed to GET when using Ajax

Tags: nginx, php, ajax

I have an Nginx server used for a store. That store has an API which is in a different folder for which i'm using an alias. Here is my `example.com` from `sites-enabled` in Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name www.example.com;

    root /var/www/store/public;

    #certificated go here [edited]

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/store/public;

    index index.php;

    #certificates go here [edited]

    location /admin {
            index index.php;
    }

    location /api {
            alias /var/www/api/public;
            
            try_files $uri $uri/ @api;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            }
    }

    location @api{
            rewrite /api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?/$1 last;
    }
  
    #the rest of the store config block [edited]
```

}

The problem that i have is that if i send a `POST` request using ajax to 'example.com/api' it is changed to a `GET` and all the parameters are lost.

Here is my `Ajax` code:

```
var foo = 'foo';
var bar = 'bar';

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',

    beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'xyz');
    },
    url: "https://example.com/api",
    data: { foo: foo, bar: bar},
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

To test this i simply dumped `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`.

If i call for `example.com/api/index.php` the request type is as it should be `POST` but if i call just `example.com/api` it is changed to `GET`.

How can i preserve the request type and parameters for a request?

Comment: That's because with that request nginx produces an internal 301 redirection `/api` -> `/api/`. Why don't simply change that AJAX URL to `https://example.com/api/` and do not invent a complex workarounds?

Comment: @IvanShatsky that was ...easy. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of a `location @api` and a `rewrite` doesn't make much sense here. As it stands, your requests have to get processed through three different `location` blocks before they are finally sent upstream to PHP.. It is also reversed from the normal pattern I would expect to see.

It looks like the request is getting mangled by the automated 301 redirect from `/api` to `/api/` that web servers always apply to paths that correspond to a directory, as Ivan Shatsky mentioned in a comment.

I would rewrite these `location` blocks as:

```
# This doesn't even need a location
rewrite /api(/.*)? /api/index.php?$1 last;

location /api/index.php {
    alias /var/www/api/public;

    try_files $uri =404;

    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

This should also allow you to use `/api` as a path without the trailing slash, though as Ivan Shatsky also pointed out, this is not a good practice to get into.

Comment: @MichaleHampton i'm getting an error when i run `nginx -t`: `nginx: [emerg] "try_files" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:5`

Comment: maybe because i have this location a bit lower into the config block: `location / {
                try_files $uri @store;
        } `?

Comment: @emma Yes, that would cause that error, though that appears unrelated to this issue.

Comment: it appears only when i change my block with the one in this comment because of this `try_files $uri =404;` line i think. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @emma About your `try_files` issue. You `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` file most likely contains `include fastcgi.conf;` line (or maybe slightly other file name). Replace `include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;` with that line in your main nginx config, you don't need anything else. `fastcgi_split_path_info` doesn't needed too. And since the only PHP file you need to serve is `index.php`, you can replace `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;` with `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/api/public/index.php` (or whatever it's full path actually is).